# Asynchronously reading multiple files in for loop

Tags: javascript, file, asynchronous

that's my javascript code so far:

files is an array of paths to html files

I want h3s, to be an array of all h3s tags of the html files.

```
function getH2OfFiles(files) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let h3s = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      fs.readFile(path.join(__src, 'documentation', files[i]), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (data.match(/<h3>(.*)<\/h3>/)) {
          //console.log("->", { file: files[i], h3: data.match(/<h3>(.*)<\/h3>/)[1] })
          h3s.push(data.match(/<h3>(.*)<\/h3>/)[1]);
        }
      })

    }
    resolve(h3s);
  });
}
```

It does not seem to work in a for loop (because it's asynchronous), but how is it realizable?

Comment: you're going to need `Promise.all` here.

Comment: @georg: Only if he/she promise-ifies `readFile`.

Comment: [Obligatory warning about regex and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterpart for the `for` loop in the promise world is `Promise.all`, often combined with `.map`. In your case, write a function that handles one file, e.g

```
function getH3OfFile(fileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(path.join('.....', fileName), 'utf8', (err, data) => 
            err
                ? reject(err)
                : resolve(data.match(/<h3>(.*)<\/h3>/))
        );
    });
}
```

and then apply it to the list of files:

```
let fileNames = [...]

Promise
   .all(fileNames.map(getH3OfFile))
   .then(h3s => ...) // h3s is an array of matches
```

(Just in case you're not aware, there's also `readFileSync`).

Comment: Probably want to filter out the `null`s.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: sure, left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there, you just have to keep track of how many callbacks you've gotten and wait to resolve until you've gotten them all. Also, use `reject(err)` rather than `throw err` if there's a problem:

```
function getH2OfFiles(files) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let h3s = [];
    let complete = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      fs.readFile(path.join(__src, 'documentation', files[i]), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) reject(err);                       // ***
        const match = data.match(/<h3>(.*)<\/h3>/);
        if (match) {                                // ***
          h3s.push(match[1]);
        }
        if (++complete === files.length) {          // ***
          resolve(h3s);                             // ***
        }                                           // ***
      })
    }
  });
}
```

(Note that I've also saved the result of the first call to `match` rather than making the regex run twice.)

**But**, beware that you can receive those completions out of order, so `h3s` may be out of order with the files (if it matters).

Or simplify through divide-and-conquer and give yourself a Promise-ified version of `readFile` and then build the results once all files are read, via `Promise.all`:

```
function readFilePromise(path, encoding) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path, encoding, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}

function getH2OfFiles(files) {
  return Promise.all(files.map(file => readFilePromise(path.join(__src, 'documentation', file), 'utf8')))
         .then(results => {
           const h3s = [];
           results.forEach(result => {
             const match = data.match(/<h3>(.*)<\/h3>/);
             if (match) {
               h3s.push(match[1]);
             }
           });
           return h3s;
         });
}
```

This also has the advantage that `Promise.all` ensures you receive the array in the same order as the original array of promises (if it matters).

(Note: There are libs that will Promise-ify NodeJS APIs for you.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) npm module. They provide synchronous iteration methods as well as different methods for control flow such as series, waterfall, parallel etc.